# How to display posts of friends who accept friend's invitation in php?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, post

I would like to display the posts of my friends (who accept invitation) just like facebook do in php, mysql.

I have 2 tables : amis (friends) and statuts (posts)

**(1) : Table : amis  (friends)**

```
id | a (which is "to")  | par (which is "by") | statut (which is "status") | time
```

**(2) : Table statuts (posts)**

```
id_statut | membre (email)  | contenu (which is "content") | id_pub (which is "id of business page" only for business account) | s_membre_id (which is "id of user") | image | nom_image (name of image) | musique (music file) | video | video_type | lat | lon | time_statut
```

I would like to select "a" (to) = $_SESSION['membre_id'] AND "par" (by) = $_SESSION['membre_id'] from table amis (friends)

Also, "a" (to) and "par" (by) = s_membre_id (id of user)

```
// lancement de la requête

$sql = "SELECT * FROM statuts AS s, amis AS a WHERE a.par='".$_SESSION['membre_id']."' AND a.statut='confirme' AND a.par = s.s_membre_id OR a.a='".$_SESSION['membre_id']."' AND a.statut='confirme' AND a.a = s.s_membre_id GROUP BY s.id_statut ORDER BY s.time_statut DESC ";

// on lance la requête (mysql_query) et on impose un message d'erreur si la requête ne se passe pas bien (or die)
$req = mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL !<br />'.$sql.'<br />'.mysql_error());

// on va scanner tous les tuples un par un
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($req)) {
```

Comment: are you sure :  *I would like to select "a" (to) = $_SESSION['membre_id'] AND "par" (by) = $_SESSION['membre_id']* that means somebody is friend to himself?

Comment: I want to select posts of user himself too

Comment: when you do AND that means not **too** that means **only** :-)

Comment: I meant WHERE "a" (to) = $_SESSION['membre_id'] AND "par" (by) = $_SESSION['membre_id']  sorry. The invitation request it means.

Comment: you just repeated the same sentence. :-) imho you should use OR

Comment: Your code seems broken of if the rest missing or irrelevant?